# Display files in java windows

Tags: java, swing, jframe, window

Hi I want to display files name in a windows with JFrame but it don't work, I don't know how to add a new element in arrayList for each files I'm short of idea...

there is the class :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;



public class InterfaceGraphique  extends JFrame  {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public InterfaceGraphique() {
       this.setTitle("My first Window");
       this.setSize(800,1000);
       this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       // First Graph Object
       Graph graph = new Graph();
       String Path = "./TEST";
       try {
           parcourir2(Path);
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       this.setContentPane(graph);

       this.setVisible(true);


   }

    public static  void parcourir2 (String Path) throws IOException {

        String[] Name = {"Point1", "Point2", "Point3","Point4","Point5","Point6","Point7","Point8","Point9","Point10"};
        Graph graph = new Graph();
           File repertoire = new File(Path);
           File[] liste = repertoire.listFiles(); 
           int y = 150;
           if (liste != null) {         
               for (int i = 0; i < liste.length; i++) {    
                   if (liste[i].isDirectory()) {
                       parcourir2(liste[i].getAbsolutePath());
                   }

                   if(liste[i].isFile()) {
                       Point Name[i] = new Point(liste[i].getName(),150,y,"normal");
                       graph.addPoint(Nom[i]);

                       System.out.println(liste[i] + "\n");
                       Test.TestFile.Afficher(liste[i]);
                   }
                   y+=50   ;
               }
           } else {
               System.err.println( "Nom de repertoire invalide");
           }

       }

}
```

and there is the class graph :

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Graph extends JPanel {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();

   @Override
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

       System.out.println("Je suis exécutée !"); 

       for (Point point : points) {

           if(point.getEtat().contentEquals("erreur")) {
               Font font = new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 20);
               g.setFont(font);
               g.setColor(Color.red); 

           } else if(point.getEtat().contentEquals("normal")) {
               Font font = new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 20);
               g.setFont(font);
               g.setColor(Color.black); 

           }else if(point.getEtat().contentEquals("valide")) {
               Font font = new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 20);
               g.setFont(font);
               g.setColor(Color.green); 
           }

           g.drawString(point.getFichier(), point.getX(), point.getX());

       }  
     }

   public void addPoint(Point point) {
       points.add(point);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
       @SuppressWarnings("unused")
       InterfaceGraphique ig = new InterfaceGraphique();

   }
}
```

It's the final step for my project it's very important, thanks for help I search since a long time.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: the two line "Point Name[i] = new Point(liste[i].getName(),150,y,"normal"); graph.addPoint(Name[i]);"

Comment: What is a Point? Also, in parcourir2 you create a Graph, add items to it, then do nothing with that Graph. And in the InterfaceGraphique constructor, you also create a Graph and do nothing with it.

Comment: I send the class point below

Comment: *"I don't know where place new graph to make it work."* Well don't add it as an answer (which I've flagged). Instead [edit] the question to add it above. But before you do, a tip: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

1. None of your methods (other than main() ) should be static.
2. It is rarely a good idea to extend JFrame.
3. Your class InterfaceGraphique serves no useful purpose.
4. rcourir2() should be an instance method of Graph.
5. All of this should be done on the EventDispatchThread, not on the main thread. Your main should create a Runnable to run on the EDT, and all of the GUI stuff done in its run() method.
6. In that run method, create a JFrame, create a Graph, add the graph to the frame, set its size or pack it, and make it visible.